# PHPSECLIB ->exec and ->write not finishing before returning true

Tags: php, matlab, phpseclib

I'm trying to call a very time intensive script from a php endpoint to a server running matlab.

I decided to use phpseclib because many people recommended it for its portability. I'm starting to wonder if I made the right decision. Maybe you can help!

The problem I'm running into is that no matter how I run the following command, it always returns true before it is finished.

```
 $read = $sftp->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
 $sftp->write("matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -logfile remote_matlab.out -r \"cd('/some_supporting_files'); some_function('/some_data_I_just_uploaded.txt'); exit;\"\r\n");
 $read2 = $sftp->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
```

I've also tried to run it like this:

```
$sftp->exec("matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -logfile remote_matlab.out -r \"cd('/some_supporting_files'); some_function('/some_data_I_just_uploaded.txt'); exit;\"");
```

I've tested everything about it (e.g. the files are there, it doesn't error out etc.) It starts correctly, but just doesn't finish. I need to know when it finishes because I need to download a file it creates.

If I add a `$sftp->setTimeout(40)` it works every time, but I'd hate to have someone wait that long if they don't need to, I also can't guarantee the script will come back by then.

Once I get this working, I still need to ping this script  from Angular.

Here is the log I'm getting:

```
"log": [
    "<-",
    "->",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.158, network: 0.038s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.001, network: 0s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT (since last: 0.453, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY (since last: 0.038, network: 0.038s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0.457, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST (since last: 0.006, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT (since last: 0.105, network: 0.105s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS (since last: 0.071, network: 0.071s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION (since last: 0.169, network: 0s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_WINDOW_ADJUST (since last: 0.043, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.036, network: 0.036s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.037, network: 0.037s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.036, network: 0.036s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.037, network: 0.036s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.034, network: 0.034s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION (since last: 0.033, network: 0.033s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS (since last: 0.041, network: 0.041s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_WINDOW_ADJUST (since last: 0.035, network: 0.035s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.003, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.032, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.01, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 2.3551, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.249, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.059, network: 0s)",
    "-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 17.339, network: 0s)",
    "<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.041, network: 0.041s)"
]
```

Comment: I also tried increasing the `set_time_limit(240000);` to 4 minutes to see if it was timing out on my end, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh! After banging my head against the wall figuratively, I noticed that every time I called `$sftp->read()` it would make slightly more progress. So then I added a do-while loop to stop when read comes black empty. It worked!

```
$output->read = [];
$read = true;
do {
    $read = $sftp->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
    $output->read[] = $read;
} while ($read);
```

`$sftp->read()` will return false if it has nothing more to read.

My full code looks like this:

```
$created = $sftp->write("matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -logfile remote_matlab.out -r \"cd('/some_supporting_files'); some_function('/some_data_I_just_uploaded.txt'); exit;\"\r\n");

$output->read = [];
$read = true;
do {
    $read = $sftp->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
    $output->read[] = $read;
} while ($read);

if(!$created){
 //continue your script
}
```

I still can't get it to work with `$sftp->exec()`

Although the above solution works, it stops working if it takes too long without giving something for $sftp->read() to read. I'm still hoping someone can solve this problem in a more robust way.

Comment: If you have to do `$sftp->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX)` multiple times then it seems like your regex could benefit from some refinement - that it's returning multiple times because it's matching the regex multiple times. As for `$sftp->exec()`...  try `$sftp->enablePTY()`. It makes exec() behave somewhat differently: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html

Comment: I tried setting the value of read to something like this `$sftp->read('UniqueString')` but it didn't work. Thanks for the feedback though, that definitely points me in another direction.

Comment: The next thing I'd do is to enable logging (`define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)`, set a really big timeout (or just set it to 0) and then do `$sftp->getLog()` to see what I was getting back. Maybe it looks the same on the screen but maybe in actuality it isn't. Like maybe you're getting back ANSI escape codes and don't realize it cause the console is essentially hiding them. If you need any assistance post the logs to pastebin.org and I can take a look.

Comment: @neubert I'm using Net_SFTP, so `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` doesn't seem to do anything. I had previously set `define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_SIMPLE)` and it wasn't that helpful.

Can you explain how to see ANSI escape codes? I'm printing the response in a web browser and can't see anything unusual.

Comment: Net_SFTP extends Net_SSH2 and SFTP operates a layer over SSH2. ie. SSH2 logs contain SFTP logs but not vice versa. Just as how TCP logs would contain HTTP logs but not the other way around. So, basically, `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` should work. It corresponds to `NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX`. I just tell people to do the number 2 instead of the constant because I don't want people trying to set NET_SSH2_LOGGING to the constant before Net/SSH2.php has been included. If you do the number 2 it doesn't matter.

Comment: Anyway, the only way `define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_SIMPLE)` would do anything is if you're doing `$sftp->getSFTPLog()`. For SSH2 logs you need to do `$sftp->getLog()` - not `$sftp->getSFTPLog()`.

Comment: @neubert thanks for all the help! :) 

I added logging with `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` and `$sftp->getLog()` but I just don't find them that helpful.

I added the log response to the original question if you want to take a look. I used simple logging because they're more readable, but I could post the others too if you like.

Comment: Yah - I want to see complex logging. They'll probably be more meaningful to me than they are to you. If they're to big you can post it on pastebin.com and post a link here. Thanks!

Comment: I can't actually paste the full log because it contains sensitive information.